# Why does text overflow inside a div?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am doing an Angular app and I have a problem with styles.

I have done a example to see the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-np12ot?file=src/app/app.component.scss

In the app, I have a div with a h1 and h2 tag inside.

```
<div class="ld-headings">
  <h1 class="ld-title">
    Títle 1
  </h1>
  <h2 class="ld-subtitle">
    The Louvre (English: /ˈluːv(rə)/ LOOV(-rə)[4]), or the Louvre Museum (French: Musée du Louvre [myze dy luvʁ] (About
    this soundlisten)), is the world's largest art museum and a historic monument in Paris, France, and is best known
    for being the home of the Mona Lisa.
  </h2>
</div>
```

And this is the css file:

```
.ld-headings {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40vh;

  .ld-title {
    padding-top: 18vh;

    margin: 0;
    width: 65%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    user-select: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  .ld-subtitle {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto',
      'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans',
      'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .landing {
    .ld-headings {
      .ld-title {
        font-size: 3em;
      }

      .ld-subtitle {
        font-size: 1em;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At the beginning, I see this and is correct:
[image]

But when I resize the browser window, the result is the next. The text is overflow:
[image]

I don't understand why this is happening when I am using the em unit. Can anyone help me?

The solution `word-break: break-all;` is useless and I want to keep the height of the div.

Comment: Probably because of width: 65%;?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because you have set a height for the div with class name ld-headings. When you remove the `height: 40vh;` it will take the content height. With browser resize text sizes getting enlarge and it should have the space to make it visible. Please check updated code.

https://angular-scss-demo-hcgg8h.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scss-demo-hcgg8h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

Comment: And If I want to keep the height? How do you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the .ld-headings parent class has a height:40vh by removing it or changing it to height:auto you can have the desired outcome.

also i believe you want the .ld-title class and .ld-subtitle class width as 65% and 50% respectively.

if so, as said above changing the height can give the desired output

*if you change color of .ld-subtitle to black and add overflow:visible to .ld-headings you can understand want i want to convey(keeping height:40vh though)*